# Github API: Get number of contributions on a day by day basis

Tags: github, get, github-api

I want to GET from the Github API, the number of contributions per day. I'm making a webapp that compares the number of github contributions to the number of Dota 2 matches I play.

This picture should explain things more clearly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ1XK.png

I have scoured the Github API and the internet looking for a simple solution and some of the answers I've seen weren't what I was looking for. This [Github API get last year of commit activity](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#commit-activity) blurb is the closest I've gotten to finding a solution, but using it would involve making the API call for ALL repos in my account and concatenating the data into one JSON. If there are no solutions to this I would like to know it so I can abandon ship.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the svg calendar data with the url :

```
https://github.com/users/USER/contributions?to=2016-12-25
```

You can set the `to` query param to your target day and then parse the svg result to get the last data in the output calendar.

For the web integration part, you can use a proxy like [urlreq](https://github.com/izuzak/urlreq). An example :

```js
const user = 'bertrandmartel';
const day = "2016-12-25";

fetch('https://urlreq.appspot.com/req?method=GET&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fusers%2F' + user + '%2Fcontributions%3Fto%3D' + day)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(text) {
    xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/xml');
    var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    var dayContributions = nodes[nodes.length-1].getAttribute('data-count');
    console.log('contributions count for ' + day + ' : ' + dayContributions);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error)
  });
```