# How can you get how many contributions a user did today with the GitHub API

Tags: github, google-chrome-extension, github-api

I am making a very simple chrome extension that displays the number of contributions you did today on GitHub. How can i get that number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Github GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/) to request [contributionsCollection](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/contributionscollection/) with a date range :

```graphql
query { 
  viewer { 
    contributionsCollection(from:"2020-05-05T00:00:00Z", to:"2020-05-05T00:00:00Z") {
      contributionCalendar{
        totalContributions
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For a specific user:

```graphql
query { 
  user(login:"krissemicolon") { 
    contributionsCollection(from:"2020-06-01T00:00:00Z", to:"2020-06-01T00:00:00Z") {
      contributionCalendar{
        totalContributions
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If using graphql API is not an option you could also parse the calendar svg, checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62030331/2614364)